# How to set a value in the RequestManager of Recyclerview in the fragment of Android app

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I am showing the images in my apps recyclerview. Here the images are loaded using the Glide v4.15.1. I am trying to set the RequestManager value in the fragment file. It have an adapter file.

How the views and position need will be set in the fragment file for the requestmanager.

```
import com.bumptech.glide.ListPreloader;
import com.bumptech.glide.ListPreloader.*;
import com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager;
import com.bumptech.glide.integration.recyclerview.RecyclerToListViewScrollListener;

    protected ViewAdapter adapter;
      
    
      public void initViews(View v, @Nullable SummaryAdConsumer consumer) {
            RequestManager requestManager = Glide.with(getContext());
             RecyclerViewPreloader<Photo> preImageLoader = new RecyclerViewPreloader<Photo>(requestManager.load(<how the image url will be get from the adapter>).into(<how to set the image view from the adapter>);
           recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(preImageLoader);
    
        }

    public final class RecyclerViewPreloader<T> extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
    
            private final RecyclerToListViewScrollListener recyclerScrollListener;
        
        
            public RecyclerViewPreloader(RequestManager requestManager, PreloadModelProvider<T> preloadModelProvider,
                                         PreloadSizeProvider<T> preloadDimensionProvider, int maxPreload) {
        
                ListPreloader<T> listPreloader = new ListPreloader<>(requestManager, preloadModelProvider,
                        preloadDimensionProvider, maxPreload);
                recyclerScrollListener = new RecyclerToListViewScrollListener(listPreloader);
            }
        }
```